# How to Solve 2 Variables Absolute Value Equation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

I want to derive the solution set of the equation

$$
-|\xi| + |\eta| + |\xi - \eta| = 0
$$
where $\xi, \eta \in \mathbb R^n$. How can I solve this?

Comment: The answer was $\{\eta = \lambda \xi : 0\le \lambda \le 1 \}$, but I don't know how to derive this set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write $x,y$ instead of $ \xi, \eta$ and $x*y$ for the usual inner produckt of $x,y$.

From $-|x| + |y| + |x - y| = 0$ we get $|x-y|^2=(|x|-|y|)^2$, hence

$|x|^2-2x*y+|y|^2=|x|^2-2|x||y|+|y|^2$, therefore $x*y=|x||y|$. In the Cauchy- Schwarz inequality we have $"="$, hence $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent. Thus, for some $t \in \mathbb R$ we have $y=tx$.

From  $x*y=|x||y|$ we get $t|x|^2=|t||x|^2$.

If $x=0$, we get $y=0$ and we are done. If $x \ne 0$, then we derive $t=|t|$ and so $t \ge 0$.

Now use $0 \le |x-y|=|x|-|y|=|x|-t|x|$ to see that $t \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|\eta|+|\xi-\eta|\ge|\eta+\xi-\eta|=|\xi|$ with equality holds if anc only if $\eta-\xi=0$ or $\eta=\rho(\xi-\eta)$ for some $\rho\ge0$. So we have

$$\eta=\xi \quad \textrm{or}\quad \eta=\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\xi$$

or equivalently,

$$\eta=\lambda\xi$$

for some $0\le\lambda\le1$.

Comment: We have $, \xi, \eta \in \mathbb R^n$ !

Comment: @Fred Missed that. Thanks for pointing out.